# vertical-align: middle not working on icon, span inside an anchor

Tags: html, css

I am working on a navigation bar for an app. Following google's material design reccomendations I have come up with specific measurements for my navigation buttons.

Now I would like to vertically align an icon and a span element inside my anchors inside my list.

This is what my links look like:

```
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <i class="navIcon material-icons md-light">info</i>
      <span class="navText">About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

I just can't seem to get `vertical-align: middle` to work.

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzsbgqk3/) to test it out. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I tried to set the vertical align on the anchor element as well, but no luck.

Comment: Would a table solve this problem?  Tables are generally much more cooperative in these situations.

Comment: did you try add this css: `.navText {
  display: block;
}`

Comment: Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzsbgqk3/1/) ... you misspelled `height`

Comment: one more suggestion: `a {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1em;
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.navItem {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 56px;
  max-width: 82px;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 56px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

}

I used flexbox, see the updated fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/qcpwev6e/

Answer (score -1):

You can make your `<ul>` have `display: table;` and then make your `.navItem` be `display: table-cell;` then you can set `vertical-align: middle;` on your `.navItem` like you wanted.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzsbgqk3/3/).

Otherwise flexbox would be good.

Answer (score -1):

add `line-height:56px;` in `li`

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.navItem {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 56px;
  max-width: 82px;
  width: 33.3%;
  background: gray;
  height:56px;
  line-height:56px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />

<link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" />

<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <i class="navIcon material-icons md-light">info</i>
      <span class="navText">About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <i class="navIcon material-icons md-light">info</i>
      <span class="navText">About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="navItem">
    <a>
      <i class="navIcon material-icons md-light">info</i>
      <span class="navText">About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```